# Discover root cause of find command running

Tags: find, process

This morning I came in and noticed my hard drive light was solid on. This was unusual so I ran `iotop` and saw a `find` command was searching my filesystem.

I decided to run `ps auxZ` to dump the processes with SELinux labels. It turns out the `find` command was running under the security context `locate_t`.

Based upon this, I came to the conclusion it was a `locate` database update.

I was wondering how could I quickly arrive at the same conclusion without looking at the security labels of processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind:

1. the parent process of `find` would indicate which process invoked it; following that process tree could lead you to `locate`; here's an example where I invoked it from a bash shell:

   ```
   (sample "ps" output to capture the "find" command)
   UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
   user     26847 20786  0 09:01 pts/0    00:00:00 find ..

   $ ps -fp 20786
   UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
   user     20786 20785  0 07:35 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
   ```

   Alternatively, as [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) suggested, run `pstree -a -p | less` for a graphical representation of the current processes; find the `find` command and trace its line left and upward.
2. identifying the start time of the `find` command could point you to scheduled cron jobs; see your system crontab files (/etc/anacrontab, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, /etc/cron.monthly, /var/spool/cron/root, etc).